# Risk in inheriting from "Event" content type?

Tags: 2007, content-type

I'm looking to inherit from the **Event content type (0x0102)** to enrich the meta data associated with **calendar** items. OOTB it's hidden but I've found many blog posts talking about how to get round this (my favoured being to simply change the group through the UI using the page `.../_layouts/ctypedit.aspx?ctype=0x0102)`.

However, no one seems to deal with the issue as to why it's hidden in the first place, and discussions around problems which may arise from extending it. Is anyone able to address these concerns?